# Logout Facebook connection on website if using javascript sdk

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have sucessfully logged in my web application, what I did is when it detects it has been logged in thru facebook, it checks if it has data in the database, if it has no data yet, it creates a record for the facebook account, then proceeds to start a session for it. But if it has a record in the database, I proceed to create a session.

However when I click on the logout button, all I do is I destroy the session for the application, not the connection with the site and facebook. How do I destroy the session given to me by facebook?(Am I using the correct terms to describe such connection between my application and facebook?)

I used the javascript SDK to connect to facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Facebook Javascript SDK, why don't simply call the `logout` method after you have destroy your session?

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
});
```

You can find more information in the [Facebook Developers Site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/)

Comment: Ah I see, I though when I read the docs I was still supposed to add some extra code to it. thanks